# Unit тестирование Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

Как правильно организовать тестирование по сценарию:

1) Добавили элемент в БД с помощью тестируемого модуля.

2) Выполнили проверку.

3) Удалили элемент из БД.

Как я понял, в Ларавел есть полный рефреш БД при тестировании. Есть ли какой то автоматический функционал, который удаляет элементы добавленные только при тестировании? Или другой подход?

Comment: трейт `use RefreshDatabase;`

Comment: @n.osennij он удаляет все элементы, а не только при тестировании. Он рефрешит полностью БД.

Comment: так используйте для тестирования бд в оперативной памяти. в `phpunit.xml` нужно `        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
        <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>`

Comment: @n.osennij Я так понимаю, по время теста делать БД  sqLite на нее накатывать миграции и сиды? А как тогда на счет картинок и файлов?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/master/mocking и в данном случае Storage::fake('public');

Comment: всё же есть в гугле, ну

Comment: @n.osennij благодарствую!

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось для этого нужен трейт:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
```